# How to find if X can be represented as the summation any Y distinct positive integers?

Tags: c++11, combinatorics, mathematical-expressions

For example if

X= 10 , Y= 3

2,3,5 and 1,4,6 are possible

However for Y=10 
This is not possible as we know we can't represent 10 as sum of 10 distinct positive integers. 
Is there a more specific way to get the results?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Any `X` greater than or equal to `S = 1 + 2 + ... + Y = Y*(Y+1)/2` can be so represented. Indeed,

```
X = 1 + 2 + ... + (Y-1) + (Y + X - S)
```

Any `X` smaller than `S` obviously cannot be.